# Can a Feathers VideoPlayer be scaled?

Tags: air, feathers-ui

It would appear that the width and height of the Feathers VideoPlayer component can be set.

But when I load a video source the size always reverts to the size of the native video.

Any ideas how to fix this?

In this example the native video is 640x390 and the player is displayed at that size.

```
_videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
_videoPlayer.setSize( 640*2, 390*2 );
_videoPlayer.validate();

addChild( _videoPlayer);
_videoPlayer.videoSource = "http://www.test.com/test.mp4";
_imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
_videoPlayer.addChild( _imageLoader );
_videoPlayer.addEventListener( Event.READY, videoPlayer_readyHandler );
_videoPlayer.addEventListener( FeathersEventType.CLEAR, videoPlayer_clearHandler );
```

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Setting the imageLoader size seems to be the answer.

```
_videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
_videoPlayer.setSize( 640*Main._starlingScale, 390*Main._starlingScale );
_videoPlayer.validate();

_containerSprite.addChild( _videoPlayer);
_videoPlayer.videoSource = "http://www.test.com/test.mp4";
_imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
_imageLoader.width = 640;
_imageLoader.height = 390;
_videoPlayer.addChild( _imageLoader );
```

//640x390 is the size of the starling display area.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `VideoPlayer` does not have a layout, so even if you set the `width` and `height` properties, it will do nothing to constrain the size of any children that you add, such as the `ImageLoader` that displays the video texture. The `VideoPlayer` is actually staying at its fixed size, but the `ImageLoader` sees that it doesn't have an explicit width/height, so it resizes itself to render the video texture at the video's native size.

You should use `VideoPlayer` with a layout. For instance, you might use `VerticalLayout`, like this:

```js
_videoPlayer.layout = new VerticalLayout();
```

And then, you can pass `VerticalLayoutData` to the `ImageLoader`, and set the `percentWidth` and `percentHeight` values to `100` to have it fill the entire bounds of the `VideoPlayer`:

```js
_imageLoader.layoutData = new VerticalLayoutData(100, 100);
```